# Where can I find the missing jetpacks

Tags: jetpack-joyride

I have updated the game but I couldn't find the fruit jetpack anywhere. I thought that I could get it by completing a specific mission but I couldn't get it, the party, nor the water jetpack. How do I get the missing jetpacks?

Answer (score 2):

As of [Version 1.5](http://halfbrick.com/jetpack-joyride/jetpack-joyride-1-5-rolling-inventory-faq/):

> All jetpacks and outfits, both new and old, are now on a giant loop. There will always be a set number of items available for purchase and these will be rotated on a weekly basis.
>
> As new items are added, others will be cycled out. These could be completely new items or fan-favourites returning to the game. The process continues until we’re back at the beginning.